# Navigation Drawer with View Pager with tabs not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, fragmentmanager

NOte: I have implemented the tabs using ViewPager. I am creating an application which has three tabs(Fragments) in a viewpager. I want to create a navigation drawer where I can see these three tabs and clicking on any navigates me to the corresponding tab.

Main Activity extends ActionBarActivity and has the following code

```
 private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

Fragment fragment = new CategoryFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(CategoryFragment.CATEGORY_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentTransaction transaction =      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.pager, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mOptionsNavDrawer[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

}

CategoryFragment looks like this

```
    public static class CategoryFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    public static final String CATEGORY_NUMBER = "category_number";

    public CategoryFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int fragmentNumber = getArguments().getInt(CATEGORY_NUMBER);
        View rootView=null;
        if(fragmentNumber==0)
        {
             rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.F1, container, false);
        }
        else if (fragmentNumber==1)
        {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.F2, container, false);
        }
        else if(fragmentNumber==2)
        {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.F3, container, false);
        }
        else
        {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.F4, container, false);
        }
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

OnCreateView function inside CategoryFragment is getting called but the Fragments(F1. F2. F3 ) are not getting set. Is there any another method of invoking these fragments? Each of these fragments are the respective tabs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement the view pager tabs with navigation Drawer in android fragment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117686/how-to-implement-the-view-pager-tabs-with-navigation-drawer-in-android-fragment)

Comment: none of them make use of ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

You need a method in your Activity that helps switch between tabs. Something like:

```
public void displayView(int position) {

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentA();               
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentB();

            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentC();

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
```

Each Fragment should be independent of each other, no need to pass the bundle info to `CategoryFragment`

Comment: I removed the CategoryFragment and implemented and displayView as you suggested. After that also it's not changing the tabs and displaying just a white page :(

Comment: @AnmolSrivastava are you still having this problem?